# OpenCV - Object in region

Tags: opencv, location, detection

I want to split image in several regions, then find square object of certain color and define in what region it is located. I've never worked with `OpenCV` and I need some tips about my further steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start reading the tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/

I'd first try to find certain colors and after that try to find their position. I wouldn't split the image. To find a certian colored object, convert your image to HSV-colorspace, then threshold it to show only objects with wanted color.

Hints: cvtColor(), threshold();

To find reqions or contours you could try findContours-method. OpenCV has very good examples.